# Use SSL with AWS Aurora

Tags: ruby, ssl, amazon-aurora

From http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Security.html, i understand i can use ssl if i connect to DB instance endpoint and if i want to connect to cluster endpoint, MySQL client needs to supports Subject Alternative Names (SAN). The links suggest using MariaDB Connector/J client as a client that supports SAN with SSL. MariaDB Connector/J client is for java application.

We want to use the cluster endpoint to connect to AWS Aurora with SSL in a Rails/Ruby application. Which client/gem supports SAN with SSL for a rails/ruby application?